# Scripts in the fragments loaded by unpoly are not executed

Tags: javascript, unpoly

I load a fragment of the page using unpoly's up.replace method.
On the page I have:

```
<div class="content"></div>
<script>
  console.log("content page is loaded");
  up.replace(".content", "/content/page", {history: false});
</script>
```

By the url /content/page I have html with the div of class "content":

```
<div class="content">
  <p>Some content</p>
  <div class="more-content"></div>
  <script>
    console.log("more content page is loaded");
    up.replace(".more-content", "/more/content/page", {history: false});
  </script>
</div>
```

And on the third page by url /more/content/page I have a div of class "more-content".

```
<div class="more-content"><p>Some more content</p></div>
```

I the content of both pages needs to be loaded but only the first one is. I see in chrome's inspector the tag script of the content page is present but it's not executed, there is no output in the console and the content of more/content page is absent. How to make the dynamically loaded script tags to be executed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unpoly will not execute `<script>` tags in loaded fragments. You need to launch all your JavaScript from compilers.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure Unpoly to run these scripts by setting:

```js
up.fragment.config.runScripts = true;
```

as can be found in the Documentation under https://unpoly.com/legacy-scripts

The proper way recommended by unpoly though is to use a compiler as mentioned